# Equivalent of nodejs crypto crypto.createSign in Python

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography

I want to get the same result with Python.

```
function generateSignature(baseString, privateKey, clientSecret) {
  var signWith = {
    key: (privateKey)
  }; // Provides private key

  if (!_.isUndefined(clientSecret) && !_.isEmpty(clientSecret)) _.set(signWith, "passphrase", clientSecret);

  // Load pem file containing the x509 cert & private key & sign the base string with it to produce the Digital Signature
  var signature = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256')
    .update(baseString)
    .sign(signWith, 'base64');

  return signature;
}
```

What I did in Python

```
    import base64
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa, rsa
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key
    private_key = load_pem_private_key(
        str.encode(str_private_key),
        password=None)

    plain_text = b'abc'
    signature = private_key.sign(
        data=plain_text,
        padding=padding.PSS(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
            salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
        ),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256()

    )

    print(base64.b64encode(signature))
```

I do not know where to start. crypto documentation is quite short. How the passphrase is used in crypto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NodeJS code uses PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, the Python code OAEPadding. To apply PKCS#1 v1.5 in Python as well, change the padding as follows:

```py
signature = private_key.sign(
    data=plain_text,
    padding=PKCS1v15(),         # Fix: Apply PKCS#1 v1.5
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256()
)
```

Comment: Why the hell someone use client secret when key is not encrypted and why is called passphrase?

Comment: The NodeJS code seem to insert the key/value pair `passphrase: <clientSecret>` into the `signWith` object if `clientSecret` is defined (in case of an encrypted key). Possibly to easily switch between unencrypted and encrypted key, e.g. in test and production environment.